# Pointers within pointers within pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

There are many questions on pointers when it comes to structs here, but what I am doing here is a little bit more complicated and has left me stumped.

I have a proc struct for xv6. I am attempting to implement mmap which takes a fd and a 0 for 'eager_mmap' or 1 for 'lazy_mmap'.

Inside of this proc struct, I declare an array of structs which will contain all of the mmaped files in that process.

```
struct proc {
    struct proc_mmap mapped_files[NOFILE];
    ....
};
```

The struct is defined here: For every mmaped region, I need to know what the address it starts at is and be able to access the size of the region.

```
struct proc_mmap
{
    int address;
    struct file *fsize;
};
```

Ok, so now for the complicated part. I can access the region via file.h. Specifically, if I go through the file struct and then the inode struct, both listed below, then i can get the size of the mmaped region, located in struct inode.

```
struct file {
    ...
    struct inode *ip; 
};
```

and

```
struct inode {
    ...
    uint size; 
};
```

Ok, now when I try to access this variable to do the eager mapping like so(where s is the index in the array),

```
uint sz = proc->mapped_files[s].fsize->ip->size;
```

the compiler tells me that the request for member 'ip' is not something in a pointer or union. But I thought what was on the left was a pointer... I am not sure what I am doing wrong even though I have tried many ways of solving this already (the last line of code is the most recent one).

I would really appreciate help but more importantly an explanation on what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
struct proc_mmap {
    int addr;
    struct file *fsize; };


struct proc {
    int proc_mmap mapped_files[30]; // was NOFILE
};
 // next two structs are in another header file
struct file {
    struct inode *ip;
}
struct inode {
    int size; 
}

int main ()
{
    struct proc process; 
    // assume on first page table 
    int s = process-> mapped_files[0].fsize->ip->size; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is 'proc' is pointer to structure of type 'proc'?

Comment: There should be `;` after struct declaration. Is this the only error your compiler tells you about?

Comment: Oh! No no, those are actually there in the code. I just didn't put them there here, Ill edit.

Comment: Post a short, entire program demonstrating your issue, as there are too many issues with definitions in the wrong order and how you declare `proc` that you could be doing wrong which are not apparent here. Works fine if you do it right: http://ideone.com/V7ElZC

Comment: @Vagish that is correct. 'proc' is a pointer to that first struct.

Comment: I'd suggest to check that all names are visible in the right places and they don't conflict with something from library. `inode` is something that could conflict. And possibly recompile.

Comment: @noc_coder: You said `proc` is a pointer to that first struct - based on the code you just posted (where its name is `process`), it clearly isn't.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I am just trying to write a smaller version of the program, but essentially, the trouble line starts with the call to the array from struct proc. I also don't understand where the 4 is coming from  in the output.

Comment: @noc_coder: There's no point writing a "smaller version of the program" if it doesn't present the problem you're describing. The `4` is just `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code compiles cleanly (to an object file):

```
struct proc_mmap
{
    int addr;
    struct file *fsize;
};

struct proc
{
    struct proc_mmap mapped_files[30];
};

struct file
{
    struct inode *ip;
};

struct inode
{
    int size;
};

extern struct proc process;

int main(void)
{
    int s = process.mapped_files[0].fsize->ip->size;
    return s;
}
```

I fixed various typos (`int` to `struct`, missing semicolons), and made `process` into an external variable so that I wouldn't get complaints about uninitialized members.

In the question code, you say:

```
// next two structs are in another header file
```

Those two structure definitions must be visible in the file containing the sample `main()` for the access to be possible.  I wonder if your trouble isn't that the header is missing from your compilation.

You can define a (pointer to a) structure type simply by mentioning it, without defining its content.  But you can't dereference the pointer or access structure members until the structure body has been defined.  This is useful for opaque types.

Comment: After including file.h, it worked. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.